# Setting a default detail page for SplitView on the iPad (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Evening all,
I'm trying to find the best way to set a default detail page/screen on the iPad when there are 0 results found. When there are more than 0 results, I'd like to show the first result on the details screen.

An example scenario would be if this was a notes app, if I had previously entered notes the app should launch with the first note page in the detail area of the splitview, if there were no notes the details area should display a custom page explaining to the user that no notes have been added at this time.

Here's the contents of a function that I've been loading in ViewDidAppear. It kind of works but it blocks the iPad slideover functionality. I'm hoping someone can recommend a cleaner, better solution than this. Thanks!

```
if self.results.count == 0 {
  if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    print("No results, loading backup screen")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("noResultsSegue", sender: self)
  }
} else {
  if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    print("Results found, show the first one")
    let initialIndexPath =  NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(initialIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.Top)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showResultSegue", sender: initialIndexPath)                
  }
}
```

Comment: Gareth, did you ever find a way to accomplish this?